# Unit test best practices to test functions that are called in other functions - to mock or not

Tags: unit-testing

I would like to ask what are the best practices to do unit tests. For example, I have a function called `inner_inner_function()` that is called in another function `inner_function()` and this `inner_function()` is called in another function called `main_function()`. Very simple examples:

```
def inner_inner_function(x, y):
    return x + y

def inner_function(x, y, z):
    a = inner_inner_function(x, y)
    return a * z

def main_function(x, y, z, w):
    return inner_function(x, y, z) -  w
```

Testing `inner_inner_function` is straightforward, but for `inner_function` I'm thinking that to make the tests independent, I should mock the call of `inner_inner_function`. Same with when testing `main_function` I should mock the call of `inner_function`. Or is it a good practice not to mock it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Best practices" is a very treacherous term. It presupposes some measurable quality of "bestness", while in fact there is no such thing. Who determines what is "best"? Usually, the term is just a synonym for "popular".

However, the popular rarely coincides with the most optimal or the most efficient; in many cases, it does not even coincide with the sensible or the logical. A few hundred years ago burning witches was considered a best practice.

The popular approach in unit testing is to mock everything that could possibly be mocked without blinking an eye. Mocking frameworks are everyone's darlings; they are used extensively all over the industry. Mocking everything enjoys so-called "best practice" status.

And admittedly, mocking frameworks are very nifty contraptions; they are ingenious; they achieve magic.

Yeah.

Don't use them.

Never mock anything.

Here are some quotes for you:

(Note: Martin Fowler is a very well-known industry speaker and author; Ian Cooper is also a known speaker; Kent beck is the inventor of, and author of the original book on, Test-Driven Development (TDD).)

- In the video Thoughtworks - TW Hangouts: Is TDD dead? ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9quxZsLcfo)) at 21':10'' Kent Beck says "My personal practice is I mock almost nothing."
- In the same video, at 23':56'' Martin Fowler adds "I'm with Kent, I hardly ever use mocks."
- In the Fragile Test section of his book xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code ([xunitpatterns.com](http://xunitpatterns.com/)) author Gerard Meszaros states that "extensive use of Mock Objects causes overcoupled tests."
- In his presentation TDD, where did it all go wrong? ([InfoQ](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/tdd-original/), [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM)) at 49':32'' Ian Cooper says "I argue quite heavily against mocks because they are overspecified."

For more about mocks, and why they are not at all the "pretty neat idea" that most people think they are, read this: [michael.gr - On Mock Objects and Mocking](https://blog.michael.gr/2023/01/mocking.html) (Disclosure: I am the author.)